# Finite potential well - transcendent equation for even solutions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, potential

I have a finite square well like the one on the picture below:

[image]

I have done some calculations on it and got a *transcendental equation* for even solutions which is like this:

$$
\boxed{\dfrac{\mathcal{K}}{\mathcal{L}} = \tan \left(\mathcal{L \dfrac{d}{2}}\right)}
$$

where:

\begin{align}
&\mathcal{K}\equiv \sqrt{\frac{2m (W - W_p)}{\hbar^2}} &&\mathcal{L} \equiv \sqrt{\frac{2mW}{\hbar^2}}
\end{align}

I have been looking in Griffith's book where he says that *transcendental equation* can be solved graphically so i did try to write it down so i could draw it (i inserted $\mathcal K$ and $\mathcal L$):

$$
\sqrt{1 - \dfrac{W_p}{W}} = \tan\left( \frac{\sqrt{2mW}}{\hbar} \frac{d}{2} \right)
$$

I noticed that i don't even know what am i looking for. Is it the total energy $W$? If so i must know potential $W_p$ outside the well, width $d$, and a mass of a particle $m$. But still how could i graphically solve this?

---

EDIT:

I set all the constants to be $W_p=d=m=\hbar=1$ and ploted a graph for an even solutions:

[image]

I allso plotted a graph for the odd solutions which for which *transcendental equation is* ($\mathcal K$ and $\mathcal L$ stay the same as before):

$$
\boxed{-\dfrac{\mathcal{L}}{\mathcal{k}} = \tan \left(\mathcal{L \dfrac{d}{2}}\right)}
$$

$$
-\sqrt{\frac{1}{1 - W_p/W}} = \tan\left( \frac{\sqrt{2mW}}{\hbar} \frac{d}{2} \right)
$$

[image]

Could anyone please confirm that i got the right graph for transcendental equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a coordinate system where $W$ (the particle energy) is on the horizontal axis. Then, do a plot of the left hand side of the equation. Then, the right hand side. The $W$ coordinate of the point where those two curves are crossing is the equation's solution; because there, the left hand and the right hand side of the equation are equal.

Of course, you need to know all the constants to draw the curves.

Here's a plot with all constants set to 1. The vertical lines don't really exist, it's just an artistical imagining by Mathematica.

[image]

- Blue: left hand side
- Red: right hand side

Comment: I already did try to plot this in gnuplot and the program had problems drawing simple tan(sqrt(x)).

Comment: Thank you for the graph i don't have Mathematica and am struggling with a gnuplot. What do intersections represent in the graph you drawed? Are those possible energy states in a finite well?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The $x$ coordinate of the intersection is the possible energy - not the vertical red lines, they are just a plot error.

Comment: Could you please allso check my edit and tell me if my graph for odd solutions is fine?

Comment: I'm not doing your homework for you :) But by the looks of it, it should be fine.

Comment: This is not a homework hehehe and the confirmation will be just fine :) Thank you!